# How to modify body class in MVC3 view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Just wanted to add a class="myClass" in body tag. Is there any html helper or something else can do this in MVC3 view page? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

This is very similar to Aaron's solution, but doesn't have the weight of a section (which at least in my mind, are for larger blocks of content than a single string).  The simplest way is to pass a variable with the ViewBag.

In your layout, just print out the class for the body tag, plus any other page specific variables (page title, extra css/js scripts, etc...)

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<html>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>@* Can easily add in per page titles too *@
    <body class="@ViewBag.BodyClass">
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, variables set in your view get passed upwards to the layout:

Index.cshtml:

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "This page title!";
    ViewBag.BodyClass = "...";
}
```

Answer (score 15):

While you may have full control of the HTML a solution was what was needed so here is one ;-)

In the _layout.cshtml page

```
<body class="@RenderSection("BodyClass", false)">
```

This will look for a section in all the child pages but says don't worry if it can't find one

Then in your child views just do this

```
@section BodyClass {productList}
```

Keep it on one line and then the outputted HTML will look fine, also you can then build up the class names as well.

```
@section BodyClass {productList generic}
```

This idea goes perfect with DOM-Ready page specific code, why not checkout 
http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/

Or my extended version here
https://github.com/AaronLayton/H5BP-Core

My way lets you do page specific code, but allows you to keep all of the Javascript in separate pages so each page becomes easily manageable. The final step would be to concatenate and minify all the JS into 1 file ;-)

Comment: Simple, Elegant and brilliant